# how to pass input string to the proxy server from my react component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set up a proxy server in order to fetch data from given api as cross domain requests are restricted but I am not able to pass the dynamic input to the query string.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const request = require("request");
const cors = require("cors");

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

// create a GET route
app.get("/liv", cors(), (req, res) => {
  var inp = req.body.asa;
  request("https://api.tonsser.com/59/clubs/search?query=" + inp, function(
    error,
    response,
    body
  ) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body);
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
});

await fetch("http://localhost:5000/liv", {
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      body: { asa: JSON.stringify(input) }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          suggestions: data.response.clubs.filter(x =>
            x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(input.toLowerCase())
          )
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("error", err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notice following points:**
* You are passing "asa" in http body and getting it from url query param.
* Why are you passing body in HTTP GET request?
       **Different ways to get the data from http request**
 **1. From Body:**
           let var = req.body;
 **2. From Query Param:**
    let var = req.query.QueryVariableName;
 **3. From Path Variable:**
    let var = req.param("pathVariableName");

**Note:** To parse the data from body you need to install body parser.
**To install:**
npm install --save body-parser
**To Use:**
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you suggest that it should be passed as "params" as part of fetch? I have tried that as well but it does not work. In general my question is does the "req.body" or "req.params" both refer to what have been set as respective body or params set is  await fetch method?

Comment: a) Do you suggest that it should be passed as "params" as part of fetch?
Yes, normally we should avoid sending body in HTTP get request until unless any specific use case. Many clients are even don't allow to send a request body in HTTP to get the call.
b) Yes if you are setting it up in body get it from the body, similarly to Query and Path.